# What's the best or most common way to pass an object's method as a callback?

Tags: javascript, function, object, callback

I've run into the problem where I need to pass an object's method as a callback, and that method uses `this`. Obviously this can't work because when invoked as a callback (not through the owning object) `this` will point to the global object.

I read about solutions to this problem and am wondering what the best or most common one is.

Currently, my 'class' looks like this:

```
function MyClass(value) {
    this.value = value;
}

MyClass.prototype.alertValue = function() {
    alert(this.value);
};
```

Options A - Change the class to look like this:

```
function MyClass(value) {
    this.value = value;

    this.alertValue = function() {
        alert(value);
    };
}
```

The advantage - simple. But the disadvantage is that `alertValue` will be copied on every instantiation, which is the reason why we usually put methods on the `prototype`.

Option B - Use `.bind()`:

```
callbackReceivingFunction(myObject.alertValue.bind(myObject));
```

I can write a utility method for this:

```
function bind(object, methodName) {
    return object[methodName].bind(object);
}
```

---

What's the most common approach to solve this problem? What are its pros and cons? Both ways I came up with seem inelegant, is there another way?

Comment: Can you give some real example? I think providing object non-static method as a callback is unintuitive. Callback is usually something more general, like a function, not something bound to any particular object. It's like an action.

Comment: Using `bind` is inelegant? That's one of the textbook situations it is supposed to cover.

Comment: @Jon So is something like `function(myObject.alertValue.bind(myObject));` common and considered okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using bind(). Keep in mind IE <= 8 does not support `Function.prototype.bind()` so you'd want to use a polyfill. If you have to bind a bunch of methods for a single class, check out [Underscore/lodash's `_.bindAll()` method](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll).

For example:

```
_.bindAll(myObj, 'alertValue', 'otherMethod', 'anotherMethod')
```